# How to disable double tap scroll using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a website and noticed when I was testing it on my iPhone that I'm able to double tap the lower half of the screen to scroll down the page in chunks. Is there a way to disable this default feature?

I have touch-action set to manipulation on the html element to get rid of the double tap to zoom feature but this does not remove double tap to scroll.

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` within a conditional that returns truthy for a double click?

Comment: Thank you! I added this to the document and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a conditional that looks for a double click and then add `event.preventDefault()...

From [MDN: The `preventDefault()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)  of the ***Event*** *interface* tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.